# Alarm Service не работает на версиях андроид выше 7.1.2

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

я пытаюсь сделать так чтобы после закрытия приложения свайпом из списка приложений, появлялись уведомления в заданное время. Я подправил манифест и сделал Alarm Service системным процессом чтобы он не удалялся после закрытия приложения

```
<service
        android:name=".Alarm.ReminderAlarmService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":ServiceProcess"/>
```

И все отлично работает на версиях Android ниже 7.1 на версиях с ОС выше 7.1 данная хитрость не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную проблему?
Ниже прилагаю код 
из **AlarmManagerProvider**

```
private int updateReminder(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    if (values.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    int rowsUpdated = database.update(ConstantsDB.DB_TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);

    if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }

    return rowsUpdated;
}

static synchronized AlarmManager getAlarmManager(Context context) {
    if (sAlarmManager == null) {
        sAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }
    return sAlarmManager;
}
```

**AlarmHelper**

```
public class AlarmHelper {
public void setAlarm(Context context, long alarmTime, Uri uri) {
AlarmManager alarmManager = AlarmReminderProvider.getAlarmManager(context);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = ReminderAlarmService.getReminderPendingIntent(context, uri);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);

    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);

    } else {

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

**ReminderAlarmService**

```
public class ReminderAlarmService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = ReminderAlarmService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;

    PendingIntent operation;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    static final String LOG_TAG = "myLog";



    // Это намерение с глубокими ссылками, для которого требуется стек задач
    public static PendingIntent getReminderPendingIntent(Context context, Uri uri) {
        Intent action = new Intent(context, ReminderAlarmService.class);
        action.setData(uri);
        return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, action, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    }

    public ReminderAlarmService() {
        super(TAG);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = intent.getData();

        // Отображение уведомления для просмотра деталей задачи
        Intent action = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);

        action.setData(uri);


        operation = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                .addNextIntentWithParentStack(action)
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Получить описание задачи
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);



        String description = "";
       try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                description = ConstantsDB.getColumnString(cursor, ConstantsDB.KEY_NAME);

            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }


        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(description)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentIntent(operation)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }

}
```

Буду признателен за любую помощь, ломаю голову уже целую неделю

Comment: `Notification.Builder` устарел, `NotificationCompat.Builder` в помощь, а также изучите его параметры и создайте канал уведомления для android oreo, ибо еще и там подводный камень вас ожидает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем все так сложно у вас?
Схема такая: создаем приемник (BroadcastReceiver), при получении сигнала он будет посылать уведомление (Notification), а Alarm Manager уже в заданное время пошлет сигнал в приемник.
Не забываем приемник указать в манифесте.

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver"/>

public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //посылаем уведомление здесь
    }
}

//в Alarm Manager помещаем следующий PendingIntent
PendingIntent.getBroadcast( context, 1, new Intent( context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class), 0);
```

Теперь про уведомление, начиная с 26 API нужно использовать каналы (NotificationChannel), иначе вы ничего не увидите.

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher )
                    .setContentTitle( title )
                    .setContentText( message )
                    .setContentIntent( pendingIntent );

                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel( channel_id, title, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                builder.setChannelId( channel_id );
                Notification notification = builder.build();
                notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: Спасибо, методом проб и ошибок у меня это получилось)